# New line in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two string in sql server 2008 r2 query. I want to make new line between these strings like and I tried to do all with char() like below, but I'm still not success.
Could you show me any thing else. thanks!!!!!!!

```
declare @text1 varchar(20) = 'First';   
declare @text2 varchar(20) = 'Last';

declare @string1 varchar(40)= @text1 + char(10) + @text2  
select @string1;  

declare @string2 varchar(40)= @text1 + char(13) + @text2  
select @string2;  

declare @string3 varchar(40)= @text1 + char(10) + char(13) + @text2  
select @string3;  

declare @string4 varchar(40)= @text1 + char(12) + @text2  
select @string4;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're executing your queries in SMSS with output set to grid. Change output to text and you'll see the line breaks are indeed there, except for the last (char(12) )

Comment: Ow! Like you say, thanks. but if i want to make a new line in SMSS how can i do.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @string5 varchar(40)= @text1 + char(13) + char(10) + @text2;
select @string5;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
declare @string6 varchar(40)= @text1 + '
' + @text2;
select @string6;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use ASCII character of carriage return `char(39)` (I forgot the exact no.) if you want it as a html `<br>` or `\n` while concatenating the string.